# Python Neural Network Backpropagation

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm learning about neural networks, specifically looking at MLPs with a back-propagation implementation. I'm trying to implement my own network in python and I thought I'd look at some other libraries before I started. After some searching I found Neil Schemenauer's python implementation bpnn.py. (http://arctrix.com/nas/python/bpnn.py)

Having worked through the code and read the first part of Christopher M. Bishops book titled 'Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition' I found an issue in the backPropagate function:

```
# calculate error terms for output
output_deltas = [0.0] * self.no
for k in range(self.no):
    error = targets[k]-self.ao[k]
    output_deltas[k] = dsigmoid(self.ao[k]) * error
```

The line of code that calculates the error is different in Bishops book. On page 145, equation 4.41 he defines the output units error as:

```
d_k = y_k - t_k
```

Where y_k are the outputs and t_k are the targets. (I'm using _ to represent subscript)
So my question is should this line of code:

```
error = targets[k]-self.ao[k]
```

Be infact:

```
error = self.ao[k] - targets[k]
```

I'm most likely completely wrong but could someone help clear up my confusion please. Thanks

Comment: Since the error is how much the result in this epoch is away from the expected, this should be the right line:
`error = targets[k]-self.ao[k]`
But both can be right, it depends on the signal of `dsigmoid(self.ao[k])` too.

Comment: Whether you derive (y-t)^2 or (t-y)^2 with respect to y makes no difference, it is always y-t, never t-y.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the error measure you use. To give just a few examples of error measures (for brevity, I'll use `ys` to mean a vector of `n` outputs and `ts` to mean a vector of `n` targets):

```
mean squared error (MSE):
    sum((y - t) ** 2 for (y, t) in zip(ys, ts)) / n

mean absolute error (MAE):
    sum(abs(y - t) for (y, t) in zip(ys, ts)) / n

mean logistic error (MLE):
    sum(-log(y) * t - log(1 - y) * (1 - t) for (y, t) in zip(ys, ts)) / n
```

Which one you use depends entirely on the context. MSE and MAE can be used for when the target outputs can take any values, and MLE gives very good results when your target outputs are either `0` or `1` and when `y` is in the *open* range `(0, 1)`.

With that said, I haven't seen the errors `y - t` or `t - y` used before (I'm not very experienced in machine learning myself). As far as I can see, the source code you provided doesn't square the difference or use the absolute value, are you sure the book doesn't either? The way I see it `y - t` or `t - y` can't be very good error measures and here's why:

```
n = 2                 # We only have two output neurons
ts = [ 0, 1 ]         # Our target outputs
ys = [ 0.999, 0.001 ] # Our sigmoid outputs

# Notice that your outputs are the exact opposite of what you want them to be.
# Yet, if you use (y - t) or (t - y) to measure your error for each neuron and
# then sum up to get the total error of the network, you get 0.
t_minus_y = (0 - 0.999) + (1 - 0.001)
y_minus_t = (0.999 - 0) + (0.001 - 1)
```

---

**Edit:** Per [alfa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342591/python-neural-network-backpropagation/16343150?noredirect=1#comment23410512_16343150), in the book, `y - t` is actually the derivative of MSE. In that case, `t - y` is incorrect. Note, however, that the actual derivative of MSE is `2 * (y - t) / n`, not simply `y - t`.

If you don't divide by `n` (so you actually have a summed squared error (SSE), not a mean squared error), then the derivative would be `2 * (y - t)`. Furthermore, if you use `SSE / 2` as your error measure, then the `1 / 2` and the `2` in the derivative cancel out and you are left with `y - t`.

Comment: The problem is: you need y-t for backpropagation (see e.g. https://github.com/OpenANN/OpenANN/blob/master/src/Net.cpp, line 323). It is not an error measure, it is the derivative of (mean) sum of squared errors. And it should make a difference whether it is y-t or t-y.

Comment: Ohh, I see, I got confused.

Comment: @alfa Are you saying in bpnn.py the current implementation is incorrect?

Comment: That seems to be the case... I will have a closer look.

Comment: @FidesFacitFidem OK, it is actually wrong, but that does not matter because, it does gradient ascent instead of gradient descent:
self.wi[i][j] = self.wi[i][j] + N*change + M*self.ci[i][j]
 You could replace the +s by -s and use error = self.ao[k] - targets[k] and would get the same result.

Comment: And in addition the implementation of the momentum is actually wrong, because it only incorporates the previous gradient. Usually it should use all previous gradients with exponentially decaying weights. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to backpropagate the derivative of

0.5*(y-t)^2 or 0.5*(t-y)^2 with respect to y

which is always

y-t = (y-t)*(+1) = (t-y)*(-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can study [this implementation of MLP](https://github.com/matousc89/padasip/blob/master/padasip/ann/mlp.py) from Padasip library.

And the documentation is [here](http://matousc89.github.io/padasip/sources/ann/mlp.html)

Answer (score 0):

In actual code, we often calculate NEGATIVE grad(of loss with regard to w), and use w += eta*grad to update weight. Actually its a grad ascent.

In some text book, POSITIVE grad is calculated and w -= eta*grad to update weight.